# Get eigenvalue from image with openCV

Tags: opencv, matrix, transpose, eigenvalue

I'm already done some step for get eigenvalue. the step i have already done is get matrix from image and get average. and now, i must get the transpose of matrix. i don't know why my source code is wrong. anyone could help?? please

Comment: noone can know, where your code is wrong *without seeing it*

Comment: i think, i want to know code for transpose matrix to complete my source

Comment: mat.t(); // is all you need for the transpose.

Answer (score 1):

just call [eigen](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#eigen) (after converting to float type) . don't bother rolling your own

Comment: can you give me complete code for get eigenvalue from a image? i'm going crazy now